# what's the reason for using `--` as as a delimiter within many shell commands?

Tags: shell

eg.

`git diff [options] [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]`

What's the reason `--` is used here? Is it to separate groups of positional parameters, namely `commit` and `path`'s? Would this explanation be consistent with other commands' usage of `--`?

Comment: It signifies **end of options**. What remains will be arguments, like `path`. Try `printf "--\n"` without first giving `printf -- "--\n"`

Comment: As options are normally given as a hyphen followed by a letter, or maybe a digit, a double hyphen is nice for saying "option: no option" - or "option: no more options". I find it nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generalized use of this sigil is specified in [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02):

> Guideline 10:
>   The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the '-' character.

Thus, paths that begin with `-` can be specified without the need for a prefix such as `./` if `--` is specified as a prior option in a tool compliant with the above guidelines.

While tools (such as `git`) that are not specified by POSIX are not required to comply with the standard, doing so remains good form.